# Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'is_processed' in 'field list'

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I wrote a `migration` to add a column to `orders` table and the `migration` ran successfully and created the column in that table.

Here is the migration:

```
class UpdateOrdersTableAddProcessedColumn extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->boolean('is_processed')
                ->after('incot')
                ->default(1);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('is_processed');
        });
    }
}
```

And here is my `model`:

```
class Order extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'multi_tenant';

    protected $table = 'orders';

    protected $fillable = ['is_processed'];
}
```

So the problem here is when I try to insert some data to the `orders` table, it gives me the following error:

> Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException(code: 42S22): SQLSTATE[42S22]:
> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'is_processed' in 'field list'
> at
> /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:79,
> PDOException(code: 42S22): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054
> Unknown column 'is_processed' in 'field list' at
> /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:77)

Here is how I am inserting the data:

```
$newOrder = new Order();
$newOrder->is_processed = 0;
$newOrder->save();
```

I have already tried clearing the `cache`, `config cache`, rolling back the migration and migrating again but it doesn't work. What is going wrong here.

My `Laravel` version is 5.5 with `PHP7.1`.

Comment: Did you also try to clean [Doctrine cache](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/caching.html#clearing-the-cache)?

Comment: @Jax-p it says, `-bash: ./doctrine: No such file or directory`

Comment: Should this not be a boolean column? You are feeding int values into a string column now?

Comment: @geertjanknapen it is actually a boolean column. Updated my question. But its still not working.

Comment: I dont know if it matters but does it make a difference if you add the `after()` part after the `default()` part?

Comment: @geertjanknapen no it doesn't actually.

Comment: Connection variable in model is correct?

Comment: @geertjanknapen yes it is.

Comment: @Saani after migrating is the column added in the database? can you check in Workbench or PhpMyAdmin or something? Just to be sure, because I am at my wits' end

Comment: @geertjanknapen yes, the column is added.

Comment: Clear cache and optimize autoload